# jayway jsonpath filter inner json array

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

I have a JSON response which I was able to filter to a format like the one below using jayway jsonpath syntax:

```
[
   {
      "entityName" : "Financial Assets",
      "entityFullPath" : [
         "Path123",
         "Alternative"
      ]
   },
   {
      "entityName" : "123",
      "entityFullPath" : [
         "Path123",
         "Alternative"
      ]
   }
]
```

jsonpath:

```
$..domainEntity[?(@.dataObjectId !== null)].['entityName','entityFullPath']
```

What I want to do further, is to get only the first value from entityFullPath array - is that case `Path123`, so the final JSON would look like this:

```
[
   {
      "entityName" : "Financial Assets",
      "entityFullPath" : [
         "Path123"
      ]
   },
   {
      "entityName" : "123",
      "entityFullPath" : [
         "Path123"
      ]
   }
]
```

Or even better (not sure if you can get rid of json array like that using only jsonpath):

```
[
   {
      "entityName" : "Financial Assets",
      "entityFullPath" : "Path123"
   },
   {
      "entityName" : "123",
      "entityFullPath" : "Path123"
     
   }
]
```

Is such drill down doable using only jsonpath? I'm using jayway flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Unlike XPath, JSONPath (as of now) offers no operations for accessing parent or sibling nodes from the given node. Furthermore, the `[,]` union operation (as commonly implemented) does not allow us to join nodes on different levels; that's why we are stuck here.

A not so elegant workaround that comes to mind is recreating the target JSON by merging the result of two (or more) individual JSONPath queries. Here is a JavaScript example of how this could look like:

```js
let json = [
   {
      "entityName" : "Financial Assets",
      "entityFullPath" : [
         "Path123",
         "Alternative"
      ]
   },
   {
      "entityName" : "123",
      "entityFullPath" : [
         "Path123",
         "Alternative"
      ]
   }
];

var a = JSONPath.JSONPath({path: '$.[*].entityName', json: json});
//= [
//   "Financial Assets",
//   "123"
//];
var b = JSONPath.JSONPath({path: '$.[*].entityFullPath.[0]', json: json});
//= [
//   "Path123",
//   "Path123"
//];
const result = Object.assign({}, [{"entityName":a[0], "extern_uid":b[0]},
                                  {"entityName":a[1], "extern_uid":b[1]}]);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath-plus@4.0.0/dist/index-umd.min.js"></script>
```

It's arguably best to work with the previous result and access the properties as needed in your regular code.